# How to read MS Outlook inbox mail using Java code?

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail

I need to read the subject,message from the inbox of Outlook, using java code. Is any sample code/Idea for the same, please help to get the same.

I search with StackOverflow, it gives the code in C#.

Also i check with Javamail, But i didnt found anything about Outlook.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780870/ideas-about-linux-based-solutions-for-parsing-email-storage-files-of-ms-outlook

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have done.

```
   /**
 * Connects to email server with credentials provided to read from a given
 * folder of the email application
 * 
 * @param username Email username (e.g. janedoe@email.com)
 * @param password Email password
 * @param server   Email server (e.g. smtp.email.com)
 * @param INBOX    Folder in email application to interact with
 * @throws Exception
 */
    public OutlookEmail() throws Exception {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");
    props.put("mail.mime.base64.ignoreerrors", "true");

    Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props);
    mailSession.setDebug(true);
    Store store = mailSession.getStore("imap");
    store.connect("outlook.office365.com", "YOUREMAILADDRESS", "YOUR PASSWORD");


    Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    System.out.println("Total Message:" + folder.getMessageCount());
    System.out.println("Unread Message:" + folder.getUnreadMessageCount());

    messages = folder.getMessages();

    for (Message mail : messages) {         



            System.out.println("*********************************");
            System.out.println("MESSAGE : \n");

            System.out.println("Subject: " + mail.getSubject());
            System.out.println("From: " + mail.getFrom()[0]);
            System.out.println("To: " + mail.getAllRecipients()[0]);
            System.out.println("Date: " + mail.getReceivedDate());
            System.out.println("Size: " + mail.getSize());
            System.out.println("Flags: " + mail.getFlags());
            System.out.println("ContentType: " + mail.getContentType());
            System.out.println("Body: \n" + getEmailBody(mail));    
            System.out.println("*******************************");          

    }
}
```

**Read from config and Pass credentials, uname, pwd as arguments and masked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to you read a .pst file using Java may not be a good option. To me it makes more sense to get the mail directly form server if you have the server details.

I got this [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/382312/java/java/Reading-pst-file) from Google-- "reading pst file".

Answer (score 0):

When you say "the inbox of Outlook", do you meanthe data Outlook stores on your local computer?  Or do you mean the data in the Inbox mail folder in your remote mail server, possibly Exchange?  If the latter, you can use JavaMail to do that, but you have to configure the Exchange server to allow IMAP access.